# Is there a comprehensive reference book on US fixed income conventions?

Tags: fixed-income, pricing-formulae

In Canadian fixed income markets there is a nice handbook called [Canadian Conventions in Fixed Income Markets (PDF)](http://iiac.ca/resources/277/canadian-conventions-in-fixed-income-markets-2007-01-01-2007.pdf).  It contains detailed market standard pricing formulas for calculating prices, coupons, accrued, and other values for various types of bonds.

Is there a similar book for US fixed income market, or its best approximation?  Preferably it would include all types of Treasury Bills/Notes/Bonds/etc, agency, munis, corporate, commercial paper, etc.  Hopefully it would also include standard formulas for call/put/floor/cap/etc, but that may be just wishful thinking.

Comment: I think Americans just read Fabozzi.

Comment: Any specific book by him?

Comment: That's an amazingly concise reference sheet, I'd love to see something similar available for the US market.  Fabozzi would be a good start.  Giddy/Damodaran from NYU also have some good material publicly available on their websites.

Comment: Second the Fabozzi recommendation. But I have to admit that cited pdf is a very neat set of conventions, given it is adhered to in all Canadian domestic FI markets.

Comment: [This guide](http://www.opengamma.com/blog/2012/04/05/interest-rate-instruments-and-market-conventions-guide) (link towards the end of the post) details several market conventions but does not cover everything you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, as suggested by everyone on and offline, the winner is...

[The Handbook of Fixed Income Securities by Frank J. Fabozzi](http://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Handbook_of_Fixed_Income_Securities.html?id=ji6O3hPSmrYC).

Answer (score 1):

It used to be (and maybe still is) Standard Securities Calculation Methods ..., a 2 volume set, but it is no longer available. You might find it in a library. It is available for $$$ at http://www.sifma.org/research/bookstore.aspx, or maybe you can find a used copy. TIPS, Inc., http://www.tipsinc.com/prods.htm, has an app and software implementing the books.